# How to run a script that can only write to STDOUT and read from STDIN?

Tags: python, perl, scripting, lua, cgi

I want my users to write code and run it inside a controlled environment, like for example Lua or Perl. My site runs on Perl CGI's.
Is there a way to run an isolated perl/Lua/python/etc script without access to the filesystem and returns data via stdout to be saved in a database?
What i need is a secure environment, how do i apply the restrictions? Thanks in advance.
FYI: I want to achieve something like ideone.com or codepad.org

I've been reading about sandboxes in Lua or inline code, but they don't allow me to limit resources and time, just operations. I think i'll have a virtual machine and run the code in there, any tips?

Comment: It is possible (see google appengine for an example of a functioning system of doing exactly this), but honestly it's a bit beyond me how you'd accomplish it.

Answer (score 3):

One idea that comes to my mind is to create a chroot'ed env for each of your user and run the user's script in that chroot'ed env.

Comment: But if i chroot a script like perl, wouldn't it have access to what the compiler/interpreter has?

Comment: If you chroot to a directory and execute the perl script in that chroot, the script would not have access to the whole of the file system.  It would have access only to the file system within that chroot.  If you want to allow access to some of the files outside the chroot, you could mount those directories within the chroot.  Read more on chroot at [link]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot}.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use Lua, take a look at this page on the Lua-users wiki:

[Sandboxes](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes)

Answer (score 0):

As jpjacobs said in Lua you can create a save environment by creating a sandbox. One way to do this in Lua is to overwrite the standard unsafe functions and call your own function instead.

Check this example:

```
function safeIORead()
    --do the processing
end

io.read = safeIORead
```

This way everytime that the function io.read is called it will point to your function and not to the standard Lua function.
It is just an example of how to use sandboxes in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

For Perl you'd probably want to use the [Safe](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Safe) module. As Joqus mentions, you'd supply your own input/output functions which you control. It's not for the faint-hearted though. If you aren't sure what you're doing, don't expose something like this to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Well for Lua module, just put critical module to nil :

```
io = nil
require = nil
dofile = nil 
-- etc ...
```

In that way you can run Lua script without problem, also i think you can use the **loadstring** function and **setfenv** so as to define your own environement for user's code.

Comment: by doing this, you put the function or the table to **nil** and then the user cannot call it / use it, if he does, it will raises an error that you can handle with pcall() function.